# OK if lechem mishneh is partially cut?

Tags: halacha, eating, challah-shabbat-bread

I'm wondering if I can use use some bread that is partially sliced (but not completely severed in two) as lechem mishneh. An example is a bagel that was cut 90% of the way through, meaning that the two halves are still attached on one end. Is this permissible? Is it less than ideal?

Answer (score 8):

[Shulchan Aruch 167:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.167.1?lang=bi) rules that during the week one should start to cut the piece he wishes to eat from the loaf before reciting *hamotzi*. However, one needs to ensure that it remains connected enough so that if he were to lift up the piece, the rest of the loaf would come with it. [Mishnah  Berurah 167:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.167.6?lang=bi) explains that if one were to cut the piece to a greater extent, the loaf would lose its status as a complete loaf.

Rema ad loc. notes that on *shabbat* one should not cut a piece until after reciting *hamotzi*. ([Mishnah Berurah 167:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.167.10?lang=bi) explains that this is due to a worry that one will cut the piece too much, to the extent that the loaf is no longer considered whole.)

However, if one forgets and cuts it before *hamotzi* as he does during the week, Rema writes that he has not done any harm.

[Mishnah Berurah 167:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.167.11?lang=bi) explains that in such a case he still fulfills *lechem mishneh* because

> שכל שאוחז בפרוסה ושאר הככר עולה עמו הוי כשלם
>
> as long as one can hold the piece and have the rest of the loaf come up with it, it is considered whole.

So, ideally, one should use a totally uncut loaf on *shabbat*. However, as long as the partially detached piece is attached enough so that one could pick it up without losing the rest of the loaf from it, one fulfills the requirement of *lechem mishneh*.